# Vanilla Openshift v3 tomcat log

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, openshift

I installed a java EE application on Openshift V3 (migrated from v2 to v3 recently)

I have a running java pod and all the function seems to work fine over web.

Almost all the openshift settings are default

All my work is on image:
**jws30-tomcat8-basic-s2i**

My biggest trouble right now is, I am not able to determine the location of all stdout from my java application deployed on server *(I dont have any personal logger, I am just doing System.out.println at various places... I know poor me)*

I went on to check "logs" directory in the pod-terminal and no files were present there.

I was wondering where is this file (containing all std outs) getting generated ?

*(I understand if somebody would need more information like some env. variable or something, let me know I will get it...altho like I said 'vanilla openshift v3 tomcat').*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two places for you to check the standard logs.  On the command line:

oc logs PODID

On the web console you can view the logs as well for a pod by looking at the pod detail.  If you want a collated view of all logs for all pods (and aggregated logging is enabled for the cluster), click on the archive link when viewing a pods logs.

Comment: I like the answer, but I would love to get onto terminal and "grep" actual file for past logs, is there a file after I rsh onto pod?

Comment: On top of @Graham answer, optionally, you could download the files through web console to investigate.

Comment: @AmanZeeKVerma The logs are not retained in the pod as applications would log them to a file, but to stdout/stderr, from which they are capture by the platform. If an OpenShift cluster has aggregated logging enabled, then the logs are captured in a EFK stack where an interface is provided for doing various queries and searches across logs. The Online Starter environment doesn't have aggregated logging yet though, only Pro.